# when i sudo apt-get update run this problem face please help me

Tags: server, lubuntu, asus

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: None of those PPAs support Bionic, and have no packages for it, thereby it's gettin 404s when trying to get version data.  You need to outright disable those PPAs.

Comment: how to resolve this error